# How to identify unique Mobile device id in Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I am using "aws-amplify" and created login ,forgot password and reset page and all are working fine with "user pool"

Now  i have use-case where we want a user can login only assign mobile device (user id bound to device id  and user cannot login from other mobile device )

in short i am looking  user can authenticate using following three attributes.

- User_id
- Password
- Mobile unique device id (Mobile Device Identifiers, or Mobile Device IDs are a unique identifier which can be used to identify a mobile device)

Has anyone solved that in Amazon Cognito ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During user authentication, the key and secret pair assigned to a remembered device is used to authenticate the device to verify that it is the same device that the user previously used to sign in to the application. APIs to see remembered devices have been added to new releases of the Android, iOS, and JavaScript SDKs. You can also see remembered devices from the Amazon Cognito console.

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/tracking-and-remembering-devices-using-amazon-cognito-your-user-pools/